# Is it wrong to ask the same question elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, hyperlinks

I just posted a question to [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/43514/how-can-i-easily-view-and-record-a-video-input-in-linux) and afterward realized that it might not be answered very quickly due to how specific it was. So I also posted it on the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7970648#post7970648)

I plan to update both the SU and Ubuntu posts with the final answer I end up using, but I can't help but feel users from both places might not like that I've posted to both.

So my question is: **Is it frowned upon to post the same question elsewhere and link to it?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why would it be wrong? Although these sites hope to become the canonical source of all programming/sysadmin/computer knowledge, we aren't exactly going to tell you what you can and can't do on other websites or forums.

Answer (score 12):

**There is absolutely nothing wrong with that.**

It is *encouraged* that you continue to seek your own answer to the question that you have. And part of that would be seeking other venues for answers. The more things you do to find the answer, the more chance there is that you'll find someone that can help you, and that is the purpose of all these sites.

All that we ask is that you update your S[O|F|U] question once you find the correct answer. Make sure that you post the resolution so that other people can benefit!

Good Luck!

Answer (score 6):

I don't see anything wrong with asking in more than one place, as long as you do as you've said you will, and update both posts with whatever pertinent information you find.

If you were to post and abandon because you went to another forum, that could be frowned upon, but then again, there probably aren't very many people who would notice and even fewer who would be bothered.

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and do it.  Then, if you get a solution from somewhere else, post it as an answer here, so we'll have the answer if somebody else has the same question.

Answer (score -5):

Only if you already know the answer.  :)

Comment: "Cross-posting" and "asking questions you know the answer to" are separate issues. It's generally considered okay to ask questions you know the answer to, too, as long as you do it constructively.